# Access db, check if someone is using... (OLEDB/C#)

Tags: c#, database, connection, oledb

I have a problem with a threaded Client/Server application, I have a serversid that has a Access DB, and with one thread for each client, but I get a problem if both client threads asks to open the DB at the same time. Is there any way to check if the DB is in use (I know I can have a varible and keep controlling/setting that, but would like to avoid that. Here is an example connection

> String connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + dbPath + "'";
>                               OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
>       OleDbCommand command;

```
connection.Open();
command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Client SET Online = " + online)
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Would really like some help!

/Nick

Comment: Can you give more details on the error you get? And some code will be helpful

Comment: the code to open a connection to db is written on server then use locking (Synchronization in threads) to allow only one user to open connection at a time.

Comment: Since you are using the OleDbConnection, set the Mode property to be 12 in your connection string - see http://www.w3schools.com/ado/prop_rec_mode.asp for a full list of modes. Simply append Mode=12 to your connection string, and the first app to open a connection will do so in exclusive mode - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/c90b1166-e5ee-43ff-a49b-9efe9f416475/ for an example, too.

Comment: You can use a try-catch block to catch the exception and branch your code to do something such as retry or exit the program.

Answer (score 1):

Per this http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007 you can set `Exclusive=1` in connection string to grant that only one connection can use this database. All another trying will fail.

Comment: That's for the OdbcConnection. You can achieve the same with the OleDbConnection by appending Mode=12 to the connection string. Otherwise, +1.